# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting on Asus X541S dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04

I have removed Linux Mint from my dual boot with Windows 10. I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxYSzxXawjU).

I tried to install new Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus X541S.

When I went to UEFI the new Ubuntu didn't show.

Disk Management in Windows show that Ubuntu has been installed on `dev/sda6` and grub was installed on `dev/sda7`.

I used the tutorial that I mentioned above to check that the bootloader was installed to UEFI. It was not.

I want to get grub2 back like I had with Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your bios is not configuring your drive as a RAID drive. I believe you need to set that to AHCI for Ubuntu to install EFI bootloader properly. I read that somewhere which I don't remember now, but I changed that on my laptop before installing 18.04 and the installer does show up in the EFI bootmanager.

Note that you need to be careful when changing it from RAID to AHCI if you have Windows installed on your machine also, you need to boot to safe mode before chaning RAID to AHCI. After booting to safe mode, Windows will adjust the driver to the correct one when you reboot back to normal windows. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will jave to reinstall the GRUB in the MBR otherwise it will not show up while starting, what you can do is just simply reinstall it and whicle installing bootloader , simply install it in the disk where the MBR is stored , that's it.